# How to make (drop-down) action occur on newly loaded page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop-down menu to make a choice for currency used. Once a choice is made the page re-loads in the chosen currency. I want the "title" tag of the currency selection made to be shown in a text-area on that newly opened webpage. I have the code to add the "title" tag in the existing opened page, but this does not put it in the text-area on the newly loaded page. It this possible to do?

And if possible when that new webpage gets refreshed by the user that the content in the text area is remembered/recalled.

These are two questions, know the answer to one, then don't hesitate, please.

My code so far:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="currency select" title="Currency Selector">
    <select name="currency" id="currencyList" onchange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"  value="GO">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" none="">$ € £</option> 
        <option value="/session/currency/usd/" title="US Dollar">USD</option>
        <option value="/session/currency/eur/" title="EURO">EUR</option>
    </select>

    <textarea id="showTitle"></textarea>

</form>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('change','#currencyList',function()
    {
       var result = $("option:selected",this).attr('title');
       $("#showTitle").text(result);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should take a look into [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Both are capable of storing that data to be pulled on page load.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll try to get my head around working with it. Seems like a good way to do it.

Comment: I have now added sessionStorage code to my code as seen below. But still there is a problem. Could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what the issue was, it was due to the `onchange` script attached directly on the dropdown that was redirecting the page (I've commented it out for now). The session data was also not being updated when the dropdown changed. Give this code a try:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="currency select" title="Currency Selector">
    <select name="currency" id="currencyList"  value="GO">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" none="">$ € £</option> 
        <option value="/session/currency/usd/" title="US Dollar">USD</option>
        <option value="/session/currency/eur/" title="EURO">EUR</option>
    </select>

    <textarea id="showTitle"></textarea>

</form>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var field = document.getElementById("showTitle");
    var savedValue = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");

    // See if we have an autosave value
    // (this will only happen if the page is accidentally refreshed)
    if (savedValue) {
    // Restore the contents of the text field
        field.value = savedValue;
        //set dropdown to session value
        $('#currencyList option[title="'+ savedValue + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    }

    // Listen for changes in the text field
    field.addEventListener("input", function() {
        // And save the results into the session storage object
        sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", this.value);
    });

   $(document).on('change','#currencyList',function(){
        //get text
       var result = $("option:selected",this).attr('title');
       //set field
       $(field).val(result);
       //set session storage item
        sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", result);
        //redirect
       window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    });

   });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the **title** of your option in a **new page**, then you should send it to the server.

The server gets that value and render it, when your new page loads it comes with the value on the textarea.

EDIT:

You have to reorganize the code to make use of **sessionStorage**.

```
<select name="currency" id="currencyList" value="GO">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" none="">$ € £</option> 
    <option value="/session/currency/usd/" title="US Dollar">USD</option>
    <option value="/session/currency/eur/" title="EURO">EUR</option>
</select>

<textarea id="showTitle"></textarea>


$(document).ready(function() {

    var field = document.getElementById("showTitle");

    // See if we have an autosave value
    // (this will only happen if the page is accidentally refreshed)
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave")) {
        // Restore the contents of the text field
        field.value = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");
    }

    // Listen for changes in the text field
    field.addEventListener("change", function() {
        // And save the results into the session storage object
        sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", field.value);
    });

    $(document).on('change', '#currencyList', function() {

        var result = $("option:selected", this).attr('title');

        $("#showTitle").text(result);

        window.document.location.href =  $("option:selected", this).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, for helping me understand a method to use.

Comment: I have now added sessionStorage code to my code as seen below. But still there is a problem. Could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

A new version of the code that also isn't doing what it should yet; the text area remains empty on the newly loaded webpage.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="currency select" title="Currency Selector">
    <select name="currency" id="currencyList" onchange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"  value="GO">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" none="">$ € £</option> 
        <option value="/session/currency/usd/" title="US Dollar">USD</option>
        <option value="/session/currency/eur/" title="EURO">EUR</option>
    </select>

    <textarea id="showTitle"></textarea>

</form>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('change','#currencyList',function()
    {
       var result = $("option:selected",this).attr('title');
       $("#showTitle").text(result);
    });

  // Get the text field that we're going to track
  var field = document.getElementById("showTitle");

  // See if we have an autosave value
  // (this will only happen if the page is accidentally refreshed)
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave")) {
  // Restore the contents of the text field
  field.value = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");
  }

  // Listen for changes in the text field
  field.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // And save the results into the session storage object
    sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", field.value);

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Fantastic!!!! Your my hero! Thanks so much!!! Only had to add   onchange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"   back in to make the page and currency change. Finished and working code as posted below.

Comment: The only thing remains is that when I use the drop-down the text area gets filled the way it should. Let's say I'm on US dollar and I change it to Euro. Then the currency for the price changes accordingly. However if I use the backspace button on my browser the currency goes back to US dollar but the text area stays in Euro. Of course,  because it's being loaded by sessionStorage. Any way around this?

Comment: Yep, you can use the value saved in session storage to select the proper drop-down option on page load. I'll update my answer. Also, in the future it's better to post updates to your question by editing it than posts answers as updates.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not, because it still does the same thing.

Comment: That's weird, I tested it before posting. Are you copying my full answer? I tweaked a bit to store the session variable for reuse.

Comment: I've edited my working code by adding your code (see EDITED). Note that in my code onchange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" is included to make the currency change on page reload. This code is not doing it yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106526/discussion-between-jesse-kernaghan-and-eddy).

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code that works:

EDITED

```
    <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="currency select" title="Currency Selector">
    <select name="currency" id="currencyList" onchange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"  value="GO">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" none="">TEST</option> 
        <option value="/session/currency/usd/" title="US Dollar">USD</option>
        <option value="/session/currency/eur/" title="EURO">EUR</option>
    </select>

    <textarea id="showTitle"></textarea>

</form>

<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
    var field = document.getElementById("showTitle");
    var savedValue = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");

    // See if we have an autosave value
    // (this will only happen if the page is accidentally refreshed)
    if (savedValue) {
    // Restore the contents of the text field
        field.value = savedValue;
        //set dropdown to session value
        $('#currencyList option[title="'+ savedValue + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    }

    // Listen for changes in the text field
    field.addEventListener("input", function() {
        // And save the results into the session storage object
        sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", this.value);
    });

   $(document).on('change','#currencyList',function(){
        //get text
       var result = $("option:selected",this).attr('title');
       //set field
       $(field).val(result);
       //set session storage item
        sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", result);
        //redirect
       //window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    });

   });

</script>
    </body>
```